# RXJS catch outer observable error and remaining sequence

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Came across an rxjs issue I can't seem to quite get. basically I have two requests:

```
const obs1$ = this.http.get('route-1')
const obs2$ = this.http.get('route-2')
```

if `obs1$` emits an error, i want to catch it and just emit a static value. but if `obs1$` completes, I want to switch into `obs2$` and not catch errors from `obs2$`. I have it working like this:

```
obs1$.pipe(
   catchError(() => of('my value')),
   switchMap((v) => v === 'my value' ? of(v) : obs2$)
).subscribe(
   (v) => console.log(v, 'got my result'),
   (e) => console.log(e, 'got an error')
)
```

but this seems a little messy and I'm wondering if there's a better way to achieve this.  I can't move the `catchError` after the `switchMap` cause then i'll be catching errors from `obs2$` as well which I do not want. I just want to skip to the end if i get an error from `obs1$`

Comment: you can just let obs1 throw and it won't execute obs2 unless you have some concern

Comment: But I need to catch obs1 errors.

Comment: If there error message is unique in the error object, then u might be able to distinguish from one single catch

Comment: Then I’m right back in this duck typing method that im trying to avoid. Looking for a solution where no matter what error or value comes out of either observable, I get the desired sequence. Want to remove the chains awareness of itself.

Comment: Probably your current approach is the most appropriate, if you have this pattern quite often, you may create a custom operator for it i think .

Answer (score 1):

You could move the `catchError` below the `switchMap` but in addition use another `catchError` for `obs2$` to not emit anything in case of it's error.

```js
obs1$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => obs2$.pipe(
    catchError(() => NEVER)       // or `of('someValue')` if you wish  
  )),
  catchError(() => of('my value')),
).subscribe(
   (v) => console.log(v, 'got my result'),
   (e) => console.log(e, 'got an error')
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I do need obs2 errors to throw. Obs1 basically checks for the existence of something, and throws an error if it doesn’t exist that I want to ignore (though I still need to get to the subscribe handler). Obs2 validates the item if it exists, I need those errors to get to the error handler.

Comment: @bryan60: This is an interesting scenario. I couldn't unfortunately come up with a cleaner solution using only standard operators.

Comment: appreciate the effort. Seems like it should be doable but it may not be except how i have it already.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```js
obs1$.pipe(
  // the happy path: `obs1$` completed successfully
  concatWith(obs2$),
  catchError(() => of("static value"))
)
```

[`concatWith`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/concatWith.ts#L96) is defined as:

```js
// `source` in this cases refers to `obs1$`
// `...args` is ...[obs2$]
concatAll()(internalFromArray([source, ...args],  )).subscribe(subscriber as any);
```

So, the only way that `obs2$` is subscribed is only if `obs$1` completes.

`concatAll()(internalFromArray([source, ...args],  ))` is a terse way of (roughly) writing:

```js
from([source, ...args]).pipe(
  concatAll(),
)
```

Now, `concatAll` is defined as [`return mergeMap(identity, concurrent);`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/mergeAll.ts#L62).

The interesting thing about `mergeAll` is that when an inner observable emits an error, the error notification will be passed along to the destination, in this case it will be `catchError`.

---

#### Quick fix

I forgot about the requirement which says that errors coming from `obs2$` should not be caught:

```js
obs1$.pipe(
  concatWith(obs2$),

  // `caught$` refers to the observable which the errors comes from
  catchError((err, caught$) => caught$ === obs1$ ? of("static value") : throwError(err));
)
```